# create a JSON Array of objects in java android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have created a class Game that looks like this:

```
public class Game{
private String name;
private String location;
private int participants;

public Game(String name, String location, int participants){
     this.name = name;
     this.location = location;
     this. participants = participatns;
}

//getters and setters of all properties
```

And I have a ArrayList that looks like this:

```
 ArrayList<Game>gameList = new ArrayList<Game>();
```

This ArrayList contains 5 games. I want to send those games to a php script so I figured that the smartest way to do this is to create a JSON array of objects and send those to the php script because those games could also be a 100 or more at some point.

My question is, how do I create a JSON array of Game objects?

Comment: look at the JSONArray and JSONObject classes

Comment: what about GSON? http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is get into GSON. [GSON web site](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/),

```
public class ExampleObject {
    public static final String API_KEY = "get_response";
    private static final String OFFSETS = "offsets";

    @SerializedName(OFFSETS)
    private List<Integer> mOffsets;



    public ExampleObject() {
        super();
    }

    public String getAPIKey() {
        return API_KEY;
    }

    public List<Integer> getOffsets() {
        return mOffsets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does GSON also work with arraylists of objects? In the examples I only see primitive types or objects.

Comment: Yes. It does. I use it for very complex object serialization and deserialization. Interesting personal experience, outbound (JAVA-to-JSON) serialization performed slower than inbound (JSON-to-JAVA) serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Use Gson: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson

```
Game game = new Game();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(game);
```

Comment: Okay, and if I have an arraylist of games. Can I just put the arraylist into the toJSON function of the gson object?

Comment: yes, have a look at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types